# AppleScript code to edit my plist

Tags: applescript

Using AppleScript, how can I edit key `PhoneNumber` to a new value and delete key `UserActive`?

I have read Apple's documentation, but I did not get any success. Thanks for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Person</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Adult</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Names</key>
            <dict>
                <key>MyName</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Adress</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Profissional</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>CelNumber</key>
                                <integer>4</integer>
                            <key>PhoneNumber</key>
                                <integer>5</integer>    
                        </dict>     
                            <key>UserActive</key>
                                <integer>0</integer>    
                    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

for edit plist file it's more simple use /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy in your script you can with PlistBuddy

```
  Clear type  Clears out all existing entries, and creates root of type
             type.  See below for a list of types.

 Print [entry]
             Prints value of entry.  If an entry is not specified, prints
             entire file. See below for an explanation of how entry works.

 Set entry value
             Sets the value at entry to value.

 Add entry type [value]
             Adds entry with type type and optional value value.  See
             below for a list of types.
```

One example for see in Terminal window : Controller:IOPCIMatch from AMD5000Controller.kext or AMDRadeonX3000.kext

```
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
do script "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:Controller:IOPCIMatch \"  /System/Library/Extensions/AMD5000Controller.kext/Contents/info.plist; 

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:AMDCedarGraphicsAccelerator\" /System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX3000.kext/Contents/info.plist

"
end tell
```

Comment: tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:Controller:IOPCIMatch \"  /System/Library/Extensions/AMD5000Controller.kext/Contents/info.plist; /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:AMDCedarGraphicsAccelerator\" /System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX3000.kext/Contents/info.plist
"
  
 end tell

Comment: Okay, i'll try this. Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
  tell application "Terminal"
activate
do script "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:Controller:IOPCIMatch \"  /System/Library/Extensions/AMD5000Controller.kext/Contents/info.plist; 

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:AMDCedarGraphicsAccelerator\" /System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX3000.kext/Contents/info.plist
"
end tell
```

Comment: One example for see in terminal window Controller:IOPCIMatch of AMD5000Controller.kext or AMDRadeonX3000.kext IOKitPersonalities